# Torsion and Torsion-Free Quotient Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The book by Fraleigh says that if $G$ is a torsion group, then so is $G/H$ for every normal subgroup $H$ in $G$. It also says if $T$ is the torsion normal subgroup of an abelian group $G$, then then $G/T$ is torsion-free.

I cannot reconcile both these facts:

1. $G$ torsion implies $G/H$ torsion
2. $H$ torsion implies $G/H$ torsion-free ($G$ abelian)

If $G$ is torsion, then shouldn't $H$ be torsion too? and that means there is a contradiction, I am hopeless

Proof 1)
Because $G$ is a torsion group, we know that $x^m = e$ in $G$ for some positive integer $m$. Computing $(xH)^m$ in $G/H$ using the representative $x$, we have $(xH)^m = x^mH = eH = H$, so $xH$ is of finite order. Because $xH$ can be any element of $G/H$, we see that $G/H$ is a torsion group.

Proof 2)
Suppose that $xT$ is of finite order in $G/T$; in particular, suppose that $(xT )^m = T$. Then $x^m \in T$. Because $T$ is a torsion group, we must have $(x^m)^r = x^{mr} = e$ in $G$ for some positive integer $r$. Thus $x$ is of finite order in $G$, so that $x \in T$. This means that $xT = T$. Thus the only element of finite order in $G/T$ is the identity $T$, so $G/T$ is a torsion-free group.

It is probably very obvious, and I apologize if it is, I just cannot wrap my head around it with exams coming up.

Comment: The second claim attributed to Fraleigh is false. Let $G=C_2\times C_2$. Then $T=C_2\times \{1\}$ is torsion and normal but the quotient is $G/T=C_2$ is not torsion free. Also what's the point of the adjective normal when we're dealing with an abelian group?

Comment: The second claim is wrong, and also every subgroup is normal in an abelian group

Comment: I copy pasted from Fraleigh! @AndresMejia

Comment: @Kam Where **exactly** in Fraleigh's book?

Comment: Pages 142,143 of his first course in abstract algebra @DonAntonio

Comment: The quoted statement refers to $T$ as **the** (not "a") torsion normal subgroup, so chances are this notion of "the torsion subgroup" was defined earlier to mean the (normal) subgroup consisting of all torsion elements of the abelian group $G$.  That is the usual meaning of "the torsion subgroup" in abelian group theory.

Comment: "torsion-free" is hard to read when dash is missing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $T$ is the torsion subgroup of an abelian group $G$, then $G/T$ is indeed torsion-free.

Indeed, if $xT$ is torsion in $G/T$, then $eT=(xT)^m=x^mT$ for some $m>0$. This means $x^m\in T$, so $(x^m)^n=e$ for some $n>0$. Therefore $x^{mn}=e$ and $x\in T$, so $xT=eT$ and there is no nontrivial torsion element in $T$.

If $G$ is already torsion, then $T=G$ and $G/T$ is the trivial group, which is torsion-free because it has no nontrivial torsion element (having no element different from the identity).

The trivial group $\{e\}$ is indeed both torsion and torsion-free. There's no contradiction.

Comment: So just to clarify:
If $H$ is THE torsion subgroup of $G$ then we have 2 cases:
1) $H=G$ if $G$ torsion
2) $H<G$ if $G$ torsion free 
In the first case, $G/H$ is trivial subgroup which is both torsion and torsion free
In the second case, $G/H$ is torsion free

Comment: Thank you by the way for your time! :)

Comment: @Kam You're welcome. You're not the only one to have had that doubt. `;-)` Not I, because my teacher immediately pointed out that the trivial group is both torsion and torsion-free. `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

The proof for the second statement is wrong.
you proved that every element of finite order in $G/T$ comes from an element of finite order.

I believe this is a counter example let $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and let $T=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$. Clearly $T$ is a normal torsion subgroup of $G$. But $G/T\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ which is not torsion-free.

Note that there is a difference between a torsion group and the torsion subgroup.

Definition (Torsion group): Let $G$ be a group, we say that $G$ is torsion if every element in $G$ is of finite order.

Definition (the Torsion subgroup): Let $G$ be a group, the torsion subgroup $T$ of $G$ is the subgroup of $G$ containing all elements of finite order. (i.e $T$ is the maximal torsion subgroup of $G$).

And I'm pretty sure that what is actually proved in the book is the following

Theorem: Let $G$ be a group and let $T$ be its torsion subgroup. Then $G/T$ is torsion-free.

Comment: @Kam I added some definitions.

Comment: Alright, you have cleared a few things up, BUT, if $G$ is torsion, then shouldn't all its subgroups be too?

Comment: you are right, if $G$ is torsion then every subgroup is a torsion group (definition 1). But there is only one torsion subgroup (definition 2) (which is?)

Comment: Itself and {e}?

Comment: The torsion subgroup is the subgroup of $G$ contains **all** the torsion elements. Since every element in $G$ is torsion you have that $T=G$. (So every subgroup is a torsion **group** (definition 1) but **the** torsion subgroup (definition 2) is only $G$ itself).

Comment: Thanks a bunch :)